# List of objects to HTML unordered list

Tags: javascript, html, object, dom, html-lists

The goal of the task is to create an unordered HTML list from list of objects given below.

My setup so far:

```js
const users = [
  { name: "Helene", age: 54, email: "helene@helene.com", },
  { name: "Janet", age: 24, email: "janet@janet.com", },
  { name: "Michel", age: 25, email: "michel@michel.com",}
];

const div = document.querySelector('.app');
let usersName = [];
let usersEmails = [];
let usersAge = [];

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  usersEmails.push(users[i].email);
  usersName.push(users[i].name);
  usersAge.push(users[i].age);;
}
for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  div.appendChild(ul);

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = [usersName[i], usersAge[i], usersEmails[i]];
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="app"></div>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR8EK.png]

The problem I have is that the information is all stacked in one 'li' element, how do I make it so that each object will have it's own 'li'?

Expected output:

```
  <ul>
    <li>Helene</li>
    <li>54</li>
    <li>helene@helene.com</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Janet</li>
    <li>24</li>
    <li>janet@janet.com</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Michel</li>
    <li>25</li>
    <li>michel@michel.com</li>
  </ul>
```

Would appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: Remove the outer for loop. You are basically creating 3 lists, 1 for each user.

Comment: Please provide an example of your expected output. At the moment we only know what you *don't* want. :-)

Comment: You want to have a list for every user or just one list for all users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the goal is to create a list of users, where each user only appear once, and all items appear in the same line, you only need a single loop to get the user, and generate the `li` item.

```js
const users = [{"name":"Helene","age":54,"email":"helene@helene.com"},{"name":"Janet","age":24,"email":"janet@janet.com"},{"name":"Michel","age":25,"email":"michel@michel.com"}];

const ul = document.querySelector('.app');

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  const user = users[i]; // user from list by index
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = `${user.name}, ${user.age}, ${user.emails}`; // create the string for the user
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<ul class="app"></ul>
```

If you want to create a sub-list of user properties, you'll need to create another `ul` inside the `li`, iterate the object properties using `for...in`, and then create `li` item for each property:

```js
const users = [{"name":"Helene","age":54,"email":"helene@helene.com"},{"name":"Janet","age":24,"email":"janet@janet.com"},{"name":"Michel","age":25,"email":"michel@michel.com"}];

const ul = document.querySelector('.app');

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  const user = users[i]; // user from list by index
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  const subUl = document.createElement('ul');
  ul.appendChild(li);
  li.appendChild(subUl);
  
  for(const key in user) {
    const val = user[key];
    const subLi = document.createElement('li');
    
    subLi.innerHTML = `${key} - ${val}`;
    subUl.appendChild(subLi);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="app"></ul>
```

Comment: Why did you remove the first loop that packs the properties of the users into separate arrays? Why do you think your answer is what OP actually wants?

Comment: @Andreas in light of the code that was in the question how do you think three separate arrays is in any way useful?

Comment: @Andy I'm not OP. Only OP knows why that setup has been used. It might have a purpose. It might not. Until that is clarified any answer is just a guess

Comment: @Andy And as we know now, OP does want a different output

Comment: @Andreas the different output doesn't mean that OP still needs three additional arrays.

Comment: @Andy That's why my comment is like it is... o.O Only OP knows what the purpose is. After the last edit we now also know what OP actually wants. And with that those arrays are useless. But that information was not available when you two added your answer which make them just some guesses...

Comment: @Andreas those arrays were always useless.

Comment: @Andy and Andreas - thank you for you comments. As to the topic itself. Many users start by not knowing what they actually need, or have a hard time explaining themselves. In the past I've engages users in lengthy discussions, which proved fruitless. I usually create an answer that seems fitting to me, and change it if the question changes or the user comments on my answer.

Comment: @OriDrori me too. Which is why my answer and yours were the same, initially, and then upvoted you because you followed through on your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is duplicating the list of user and you want to have just one list for all users you can easily remove your second iteration on users like this:

```js
const users = [{
  name: "Helene",
  age: 54,
  email: "helene@helene.com",
}, {
  name: "Janet",
  age: 24,
  email: "janet@janet.com",
}, {
  name: "Michel",
  age: 25,
  email: "michel@michel.com",
}];


const div = document.querySelector('.app');
let usersName = [];
let usersEmails = [];
let usersAge = [];

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  usersEmails.push(users[i].email);
  usersName.push(users[i].name);
  usersAge.push(users[i].age);;
}

var ul = document.createElement('ul');
div.appendChild(ul);
for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = [usersName[i], usersAge[i], usersEmails[i]];
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<div class="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate twice for achieving your goal. First, you need to loop through the array using `map` or `for` keywords, and then when you have an object, you need to iterate over the object using `Object.keys`. Something like this:

```js
const users = [
{
  name: "Helene",
  age: 54,
  email: "helene@helene.com",
}, {
  name: "Janet",
  age: 24,
  email: "janet@janet.com",
}, {
  name: "Michel",
  age: 25,
  email: "michel@michel.com",
}];

// first, you need to loop through the array to get each user and then iterate over the user itself for its properties


users.map(user=> {

  Object.keys(user).map(key => {
      console.log(user[key])
      // we are printing the 'key' property of the user Object.
  }) 
      // the above is the one you want; you can push it to an array and then render it in your HTML file
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You've made things a little more complicated that you need to. You need one `div`, and one `ul`. When you loop over the data you can create a new `li` with each iteration and then attach the user data to its text content. Then attach the `li` the `ul`, and then, finally, after the loop, attach the `ul` to the page.

```js
const users=[{name:"Helene",age:54,email:"helene@helene.com"},{name:"Janet",age:24,email:"janet@janet.com"},{name:"Michel",age:25,email:"michel@michel.com"}];

const div = document.querySelector('.app');
const ul = document.createElement('ul');

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  const user = users[i];
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = `${user.name}, ${user.age}, ${user.email}`;
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

div.appendChild(ul);
```

```html
<div class="app"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)